# reagentc /enable REAGENTC.EXE: Operation failed: 2

Tags: windows-11

I used this video to try to repair the WindowsRE recovery partition on my main hard disk.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJt7TNcN7iQ

At the end of the video when he wants to enable Windows Recovery Environment, in dos prompt administrator, he writes "reagentc: /enable" and is enabled without problems.

In my case, when I write the same commands, appears this error: "REAGENTC.EXE: Operation failed: 2 - REAGENTC.EXE: An error has occurred".

Someone can help me?

Comment: Suspect your error message is incomplete, if it contains `3ee`, that means it cannot find your current recovery image. Can you provide a screenshot of your current partitions on your  disk? Avoid making any changes, I suspect I know what the problem is, but I cannot help if you continue to make changes to your system.